# Do not filter results in jquery/asp.net autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have the jquery autocomplete done with ajax call. I am doing filter in my code behind method. I do not want to filter them in the UI. How to do that. To be more specific if the user types 'St.' for e.g. I am returning values which has 'St.' as well as 'Saint' in the results. But jquery is not displaying the results with 'Saint'. how can I get jquery autocomplete to display 'Saint' as well?

Code in Jquery

```
 function GetNames(text) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Default.aspx/GetSchools",
dataType: "json",
data: '{ "data":"' + text + '"}',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(data) {
$('#university').autocomplete({
source: data.d,
focus: function(event, ui) {
$('#university').val(ui.item.Descr);
return false;
},
select: function(event, ui) {
$('#university').val(ui.item.Descr);
$('#universityID').val(ui.item.UnivCode);
return false;
}
});
}
});
}
```

Code Behind in .cs file

```
public static List<DataClass.School> GetSchools(string data)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Schools"];

            data = data.ToLower();
            Debug.WriteLine(data);

            var ret = new List<TestApplication.DataClass.School>();
            ret = (from l in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   let s = l["Descr"].ToString().ToLower()
                   where (s.Contains(data) || s.Contains("saint"))
                   select new TestApplication.DataClass.School
                   {
                       Descr = l["Descr"].ToString(),
                       UnivCode = l["UnivCode"].ToString()
                   }).Take(20).ToList();

            Debug.WriteLine(ret.Count.ToString());

        return ret.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: If you show us your code we can better help

Comment: Okay. I tried the same with AjaxAutocomplete and it works fine. I am not sure what I am missing in JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

it should be as simple as setting the source to the url similar to the example in the [jqueryui documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)

Comment: I have set the source, but I do not want to filter the results. E.g. as I mentioned earlier, if user types Jr - i am returning results which contains Junior as well. I do NOT want those to be filtered by jquery.

Comment: that's got nothing to do with jquery. the results are coming from the server. this is where you would query for the results. so how you query for the results will determine what is returned to the client.

Comment: Even after the results are returned not all the values are shown in the dropdown. That is where I have the problem. if you see the above code and possible hardcode Jr and Junior, the dropdown in the autocomplete will show only Jr if you type Jr and not Junior. I do not want that filter happening.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Somewhere on the web it stated I can probably change the jQuery. Since I am filtering the results in the codebehind, I changed my jQuery not to filter anything. In the autocomplete extension method of jquery-ui.js changed to

```
var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(''), "i");
```

This works great.